# Checking length of element in beforeEach on Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to setup my `beforeEach` to create a new email if none exist before starting my tests, but when I try to count how many emails there are in my `beforeEach`, it always logs as `0`, even if there are more. If I log the `count` in my `it` block, it shows the correct count.

Does this look correct? How can I properly check the `count` in the `beforeEach` so that it doesn't always create a new email for every test?

```js
describe("email", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit("/");

    let count = Cypress.$('#emails').length

    // always logs 0
    cy.log(count)

    if(count == 0) {
      createNewEmail()
    }
  });

  it("email", () => {
    let count = Cypress.$('#emails').length

    // logs correct amount
    cy.log(count)
  });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I execute code before all tests suite with Cypress?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48110258/8839059)

Comment: @RafaelTavares that doesn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cypress commands are asynchronous](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress#Commands-Are-Asynchronous). So when the test executes `cy.visit("/")` it does not mean that the next line will be executed after the page gets really loaded.

You can fix this as follows:

```js
 beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit("/").then(() => {
      let count = Cypress.$('#emails').length
      cy.log(count)
      if(count == 0) {
        createNewEmail()
      }
    })
}
```