# How to run command before the first test runs using Cypress

Tags: cypress

I want to execute a command that sets up fixtures, before the first test. But it shouldn't run before *every* test - just before the first one.

I'm trying to get the feature flags for the deployed application, that I'm testing against (local, staging or production). In the application, the feature flags are stored on the `window` object: `window.featureFlags`. My `setupFixtures` function should save those feature flags into my `fixtures/feature-flags.json`. This way, I'll be able to see if a feature is enabled, based on the deployed code.

And then I can add this to all my tests:

```
beforeEach( function(){
  if( !isFeatureEnabled( 'FEATURENAME' ) ){
    this.skip();
  }
});
```

Meaning that it'll then get the featureName from the given deployed code. And if the featureName isn't enabled, then it'll automatically skip that test.

- If I run a single test called `test-header.cy.ts`, then I would like my tests to do this:

  - Get the feature flags and save them to `fixtures/feature-flags.json`
  - Run the `test-header.cy.ts` test
- If I have three tests: `test-x.cy.ts`, `test-y.cy.ts` and `test-z.cy.ts`, then I would like it to do this:

  - Get the feature flags and save them to `fixtures/feature-flags.json`
  - Run the `test-x.cy.ts` test
  - Run the `test-y.cy.ts` test
  - Run the `test-z.cy.ts` test

How do I do this?

I've tried:

1. Add a `before` part to my `e2e.ts` file:

   This requires defining some helper-function and tasks, but if I do this:

   ```
   // Add isFeaturedEnabled globally (so we don't need to import it every time)
   function isFeatureEnabled(featureName) {
     if (!globalThis.featureFlags) {
       throw new Error('Feature flags are not set');
     }

     const feature = globalThis.featureFlags.find((feature) => feature.name === featureName);
     return Boolean(feature && feature.enabled);
   }

   globalThis.isFeatureEnabled = isFeatureEnabled; // Attach the function to the global scope
   // END OF: Add isFeaturedEnabled globally

   before(() => {
     const filePath = 'cypress/fixtures/tmp/featureFlags.json';

     // Reset featureFlags, to ensure to get the latest one
     cy.task('fileExists', filePath)
       .then((exists) => {
         if (exists) {
           cy.exec(`rm ${filePath}`);
         }
       })
       .then(() => {
         cy.visit('/');
         cy.window().then((win) => {
           if (win.featureFlags && win.featureFlags.length > 0) {
             cy.writeFile(filePath, win.featureFlags);
             globalThis.featureFlags = win.featureFlags;
           } else {
             cy.writeFile(filePath, []);
             globalThis.featureFlags = [];
           }
         });
       });
   });
   ```

   This is working. But it means that it generates a new `cypress/fixtures/tmp/featureFlags.json` before every individual test, which is quite a bit of time wasted. Especially since it needs to load the home page anew every time (for the window-object to be accessible).
2. Make a 'Setup test' bash script or something

   I could make a little mini-script, that sets up up the feature-flag fixture before I run my tests. This is also a good option, but it would also heighten the chance of my colleagues forgetting to run that anew when they run against a different environment, giving them false negatives.

Comment: Why not make a `preX` script in your package file, so e.g. `npm run e2e` automatically runs `npm run pree2e` for the one-off setup?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I execute code before all tests suite with Cypress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48110258/how-can-i-execute-code-before-all-tests-suite-with-cypress)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to run your code only once for all specs in the run, you should be using the [Before Run API](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/before-run-api) instead of the `before()` hook.

Since it runs in the Node process, use fs.unlink to delete the file.

The example from the docs:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  // setupNodeEvents can be defined in either
  // the e2e or component configuration
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('before:run', (details) => {
        /* code that needs to run before all specs */
      })
    },
    experimentalInteractiveRunEvents: true,   // use for cypress open mode
  },
})
```

---

However, the code you have looks **quite unnecessary**, I would read the `win.features` property into an env var **on every visit**.

See [Cypress.env](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/env)

> **Scope**
>
> Environment variables set using Cypress.env are only in scope for the current spec file.
>
> Cypress runs each spec file in isolation: **the browser is exited between specs.**

```js
cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/#/users', {
  onLoad: (win) => {
    const flags = win.featureFlags || []  // default to empty
    Cypress.env('flags', flags)
  },
})
```

`Cypress.env()` is provided so that you can avoid global pollution and unexpected bugs due to test cleardown. Your current approach is unlikely to survive test isolation best practices.